# Bending animation with rig?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to make an android animation, but I am stuck at the rigging part. I want his arms and legs to be able to bend like plastic / rubber and use a rig. I've heard of lattice modifier, but that doesn't include a rig / spline / IK setup. When I use a regular rig, it bends hard at the bones.

I am relatively inexperienced with blender, so I've included a picture of what I'm trying to do. I can probably explain better than I can.

[image]

It does look a little funky in the picture, but I think it would look nice in an animation :).

Thank you so much for any help!!

Edit: Added a picture to better show what I mean
[image]

Comment: maybe using b-bones? see https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/armatures/properties/display.html

Answer (score 1):

I think a pretty efficient way to solve this would be to have a more distributed (softer) weight paint on the armature rig. This way, the bones will not bend so sharply.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you both for the replies! I will try both ways - b bones with light weights sounds like the winner!

Comment: Everything has worked out so far, but now when I move his elbow bone or the top of his shoulder, it morphs the actual body out of proportion. I think soft or empty weight paint from the arm to the body would fix this, but I cant click on / or select the body to paint it? They are seperate meshes, if that helps. How could I fix this? I've added a picture to show what I mean.

Comment: You can check and edit the weight paint for each bone by selecting the armature, then the mesh, and then pressing the 'tab' key.